# Get the product ids with the checkbox and create a new array with the ids

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I am a new student of typescript/angular2+ and I am developing a website to practice my studies.

I already made the view and now I am creating the update page but I have some problems to finish.

My update page has 2 selects and 1 table with 1 or more checkboxes.

In select I'm using (valueChanged) to get the select id
in Table I'm using o [(ngModel)] to get the select all

In summary I do this:
get the select id 1
get id of 1 or more products by selecting the checkbox
get the id of select 2

When I select the checkbox it is returning this array but I only need the id that is in the array to be able to send it to the backend, but it also has to be an array because my backend is configured to accept a list. I'm using DTO (Data Transfer Object).

[{"id": 2225, "name": "Joy Price", "isSelected": true}, {"id": 2226, "name": "Ronnie Jordan", "isSelected": true}]

In summary

I'm needing get the checkedCategoryList ids and create a new array to send to the idsProducts that is in the model.

What is the best way to do this?
at the moment I am not able to progress in this problem

***update.component.html***

```
<app-vo-modal keyTitle="Update" keySubtitle="" >


    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required">Choose product</label>
            <app-vo-select [itens]="productItens" (valueChanged)="showValues($event)" formControlName="product"></app-vo-select>
        </div>
    </form>


    <div>
        <tbody>
        <table class="table table-striped text-center">
            <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isMasterSel" name="name" value="h1" (change)="checkUncheckAll()"/>
            </th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr class="text-center" *ngFor="let prod of showTable; index as i">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="prod.isSelected" name="name" value="{{prod.id}}" (change)="isAllSelected()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{prod.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required">Choose product the substitute</label>
            <app-vo-select [itens]="productItens" formControlName="product"></app-vo-select>
        </div>
    </form>
</app-vo-modal>
```

***update.component.ts***

```
export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {


    products: UpdateModelComponent[] = [];
    showTable: UpdateModelComponent[] = [];
    productItens: SelectOption[];
    form: FormGroup;
    isMasterSel: boolean;
    categoryList: any;
    checkedCategoryList: any;

    @Output()
    valueChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @Output()
    dataSave = new EventEmitter<any[]>();


    constructor(
        private service: UpdateService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
        ) {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        product: []
    });


    showValues(id: number) {
        this.service.childproduct(id).
        subscribe((element: EntityBase<UpdateModelComponent>) => {
            this.showTable = element.content;
        });
    }
 
    ngOnInit() {
       
        this.service.parentProduct().
        subscribe((element: EntityBase<UpdateModelComponent>) => {
            this.products = element.content;
            console.log(this.products);
            this.productItens =  this.products.map(t => ({  id: t.id.toString(), text: t.nome }));
        });

    }

     onModalConfirm() {
        
        const a = new UpdateModelComponent();
        this.service.save(a).subscribe(r => {
        });
    }

    checkUncheckAll() {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.showTable.length; i++) {
              this.showTable[i].isSelected = this.isMasterSel;
            }
              this.getCheckedItemList();
    }

    isAllSelected() {
            this.isMasterSel = this.showTable.every(function(item: any) {
                return item.isSelected === true;
              });
            this.getCheckedItemList();
    }

    getCheckedItemList() {
        this.checkedCategoryList = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.showTable.length; i++) {
            if (this.showTable[i].isSelected) {
                this.checkedCategoryList.push(this.showTable[i]);
            }
        }
        this.checkedCategoryList = JSON.stringify(this.checkedCategoryList);
        console.log(this.checkedCategoryList); 

> result : array/object of selected products 
> result : [{"id":2225,"name":"Joy Price", "isSelected":true}, {"id":2226,"name":"Ronnie Jordan", "isSelected":true}]


    }
}
```

***update.model.ts***

```
export class UpdateModelComponent {

    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public components: UpdateModelComponent[] = [];
    public isSelected = false;

    public idsProducts: [];
    public currentProduct: number;
    public newProduct: number;
}
```

***update.service.ts***

```
export class UpdateService {

    PATH = '/server/api/product';

    constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    childproduct(page?: Paging): Observable<EntityBase<UpdateModelComponent>> {

        if (!page) {
            page = new Paging();
        }
        return this.httpClient.get<EntityBase<UpdateModelComponent>>(`${this.PATH}/${paginacao.toString()}`);
    }

    parentProduct(id: number): Observable<EntityBase<UpdateModelComponent>> {
        return this.httpClient.get<EntityBase<UpdateModelComponent>>(`${this.PATH}/v2/${id}`);
    }

    save(components: UpdateModelComponent): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.put<any>(`${this.PATH}`, components);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**update in 9-9-2021**

you can use Set

example:-

component ts

```
 uniqueIdsUsingSet: Set<number> = new Set();

  prods = [
    { id: 2225, name: 'Joy Price' },
    { id: 2226, name: 'Jordan Ronnie ' },
    { id: 2227, name: 'Price Jordan' },
    { id: 2228, name: 'Ronnie Joy' },
  ];

 uniqueArryUsingSet(item: HTMLInputElement): void {
  if(item.checked) {
   this.uniqueIdsUsingSet.add(+item.id);
  } else {
   this.uniqueIdsUsingSet.delete(+item.id);
  }
 }
```

component HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let prod of prods">
  <div>
    <label [for]="prod.id">
      {{prod?.name}}
    </label>
    <input
      [id]="prod.id"
      type="checkbox"
      [value]="prod.id"
      #item
     (change)="uniqueArryUsingSet(item)"
    />
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**old answer**

in Component ts file

```
  uniqueIds: any[] = [];

  prods = [
    { id: 2225, name: 'Joy Price' },
    { id: 2226, name: 'Jordan Ronnie ' },
    { id: 2227, name: 'Price Jordan' },
    { id: 2228, name: 'Ronnie Joy' },
  ];

  makeUniqueArrayItems(item: HTMLInputElement): void {
    const itemIndex = this.uniqueIds.indexOf(item.id);
    !item.checked
      ? this.uniqueIds.splice(itemIndex, 1)
      : this.uniqueIds.push(item.id);

    this.uniqueIds = [...new Set(this.uniqueIds)];
  }
```

in component HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let prod of prods">
  <div>
    <label [for]="prod.id">
      {{prod?.name}}
    </label>
    <input
      [id]="prod.id"
      type="checkbox"
      [value]="prod.id"
      #c
      (change)="makeUniqueArrayItems(c)"
    />
  </div>
</ng-container>


<div *ngIf="uniqueIds?.length">
  <h3>
    values
  </h3>
{{uniqueIds}}

</div>
```

example on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uniqu-select-arr?file=src/app/app.component.html